# Is it useful to track dev time with CI/CD?

Tags: cicd, capacity-planning, jira

Estimating is hard, but it is made easier with good record keeping.
Is there a known solution to tracking dev time on a ticket by making use of CI/CD to update JIRA tickets or the like with logged worked time, based on the time difference between first commit and final CD?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the rich jira rest API for this kind of automation work. Jira API provides mechanism to update logged hours using **PUT /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/worklog/{id}**

You can use this rest API endpoint to update the corresponding issue with the difference of first commit timestamp and first successful CD.

Find more about it [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/?_ga=2.140150195.1003517421.1559277802-1541541824.1536148219#api/2/issue-updateWorklog).